# Handling multiple device authentication with same user in a database

Tags: reactjs, laravel, rest, api, authentication

So i'm buidling a rest api on laravel to be used by mobile and web apps ,
my question is how to handle same user authentication on multiple devices in the database side i'm thinking of generating a jwt token based on device_id and user_id , however i want to be able to revoke a token thus blocking a user on all devices , any ideas how to manage will be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport It shows you how to configure your API and frontend. It utilizes jwt strings under the hood. They have a bunch of migration and canned operations already set up for you so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Once you get that implemented, inside of Providers/AppServiceProviders boot method or anywhere else essentially, you can figure out who the user is and what device they are using and if they are active. You can then return what ever error exception you want if you need to. `throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication Exception");`